# Regression test with Visual Studio test project, start/debug application automatically

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, testing, automated-tests

I want to run regression tests with Visual Studio 2010 or 2013, which start the application for each test, after cleaning up previous tests, setting up specific application config and database config/objects.

They are **not** unit tests, no application code/objects linked into the tests. They only create application config+input and check results. Application type is an executable with console window from VS, on database backend, stopping on enter key in console, and installed as a Windows service.

```
/* pseudo code */

[TestMethod]
public void ProcessCustomerOrderTest()
{
    bool isDebugMode = FindOutIfIsDebugModeSomehow();

    var orderData = CreateOrderDataSomehow(); /* real code here */
    SetupNewCustomerOrderInDatabase(orderData);

    /* Running/debugging the application VS project is preferred 
    over a new Process() for an executable! */
    using(var applProc = new Process()) 
    {
        /* setup and start applProc */
        /* or VS project debugging */
        if (isDebugMode)
        {
            AttachVsDebuggerToProcess(applProc); 
            /* any real code for this? */
        }

        while(!CheckIsOrderDataProcessed(orderData) 
            && !applProc.HasExited)
        { 
            Thread.Sleep(5000); 
        }

        if (!applProc.HasExited)
        {
            SignalApplStop(applProc); /* let it finish, don't kill */
            applProc.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    CheckProcessOrderResultsInDatabase(); /* real check code here */
}
```

I know how to do it manually, putting breaks (debug breakpoint or dialog window "Start application now!") in the test, then starting the application manually. But for 20 to 30 tests, each taking a few minutes, this is tedious and a waste of time.

One purpose is to run a test suite automatically from VS, so I can run it during lunch break or meetings, without need to start/stop anything (this one likely without debug breaks).

It shall also be possible to debug from VS, debugging both tests and application at the same time, without the need to start/stop or attach to a process manually, breaking only when a problem occurs. So I can do something else in the meantime.

I think there is a solution and tutorials for this, I just didn't find the right ones (not GUI test, not unit test, not the new test frameworks coming with VS 2015 Enterprise, TFS and others - I'll likely use the latter another time, but need a simple solution for now).

Answer (score 0):

To break and attach with code instead of manually, take a look at System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx

Take a look at #if to determine if debug.

```
 #define DEBUG
// ...
#if DEBUG
   Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but manual break and attach is quite exactly what I want to get rid of. #if DEBUG is likely good to determie if in debug mode. When running in Visual Studio, I would even prefer to run the application startup project with current debug settings, over setting up an executable for a Process.

Comment: Manually attach and break probably were not the correct words. The process will break and ask to be debugged when it hits that line.